# Mailgun View Stored Messages PHP

Tags: php, api, mailgun

I am trying to view stored message content via the MailGun `PHP` API.  Getting the message ID is easy enough, as I just grab the recent log activity.

```
$mg = Mailgun::create('MY API KEY');
$domain = 'mydomain.com';
$result = $mg->get("$domain/log", array(
    'limit' => 300
));
print_r($result);
```

The result looks like:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [http_response_body] => stdClass Object
        (
            [total_count] => 9958
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [hap] => opened
                            [message] => Opened: email@example.com
                            [type] => info
                            [created_at] => Wed, 16 Dec 2020 19:42:40 -0000
                            [message_id] => xxxx@mydomain.com
                        )

                )

        )

    [http_response_code] => 200
)
```

I now have the `message_id` and I would like to VIEW that message ...  I imagine it's going to be something LIKE this:

```
$result = $mg->get("$domain/message", array(
    'message_id' => 'xxxx@mydomain.com'
));
```

But alas it only returns a status `200`

I've viewed their documentation on the [Python Version](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-events.html#viewing-stored-messages) ... however I cannot for the life of my find how to view a single email in `PHP`.  I think I am super close, I am certain that I am just missing the parameter naming convention ... I think. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Hi did you get the solution? I just stuck on the same point and struggling

Comment: Not yet!  This is a low priority project so I was patiently waiting for a response.

Comment: got it just found it

Answer (score 0):

I am using the **mailgun/mailgun-php": "^3.0** for the mail sending, and this is how I got the message content form the mailgun storage

```
    $msg_id  = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.xxx';
    $mg = Mailgun::create('key-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    // here you have got the single email with complete response
    $res =  $mg->events()->get('xxxxxxxxx.xx.xx',array('message-id'=>$msg_id));
    $stor = $res->getStorage();
    
   //and here you have got the URL and Key and you can use these parmas to get the message with curl

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $stor['url']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "api:{key which return in the above object}");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    $jo = json_decode($output,true);
    
    curl_close($ch);
```

[[api response][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/syYrV.png